# Laravel How to create One Query in order to Produce Multiple Foreach on View

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

For performance, I'm trying to create only one query to db and display multiple foreach in view blade. In order to produce this result, my approach was to use query builder and selectRaw to create filters.

My current code:

```
$totals = DB::table('product')->select('productName','sellingPrice','productSpecification')
            ->selectRaw("(case where categoryId = '177' then 1 end) as computers")
            ->selectRaw("(case where categoryId = '31388' then 1 end) as cameras")
            ->selectRaw("(case where categoryId = '9355' then 1 end) as mobiles")
            ->get();
    }
```

The idea is to use selectraw in the following way at blade views:

```
@foreach ($totals->computers as $productcomputers)

@foreach ($totals->cameras as $productcameras)

@foreach ($totals->mobiles as $productmobiles)
```

I tried the approach but Im receiving error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where
>   categoryId = '177' then 1 end) as computers

Any suggestion to produce one query with multiple foreach in laravel or to solve the current approach?

brgds,

Comment: What are you hoping to get for the values of `computers`, `cameras` and `mobiles` here?

Comment: @Rwd the idea is to use only one query for multiple foreach. right now I have a view with multiple queries to the same table producing one foreach per query. I want to create a better performance.

Comment: @Rwd I took the idea from Reinik calculating totals using conditionals https://reinink.ca/articles/calculating-totals-in-laravel-using-conditional-aggregates

Comment: All of those are aggregates e.g. `counts` which you wouldn't loop through anyway.

Comment: @Rwd ok, thank you. that was my question, if it was possible to solve this approach or create a new one. I will work in a different direction. thank you so much!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$totals = DB::table('product')->select('productName','sellingPrice','productSpecification')
            ->whereIn('categoryId', [177, 31388, 9355])
            ->selectRaw("(case when categoryId = '177' then 1 end) as computers")
            ->selectRaw("(case when categoryId = '31388' then 1 end) as cameras")
            ->selectRaw("(case when categoryId = '9355' then 1 end) as mobiles")
            ->get();

        $data = collect();
        $data->computers = $totals->where('computers', '!=', null);
        $data->cameras   = $totals->where('cameras', '!=', null);
        $data->mobiles   = $totals->where('mobiles', '!=', null);
```

Now use at blade views

```
@foreach ($data->computers as $productcomputers)

@foreach ($data->cameras as $productcameras)

@foreach ($data->mobiles as $productmobiles)
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `case where` by `case when`.
You can check the documentation at [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp).

Comment: thanks @bram-verstraten:  when works for the sql, Now Im receiving "Property [computers] does not exist on this collection instance" but from laravel.